# Multiple instance of pinia store possible in same page or same component?

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I have a pinia store which is products store. I use it in products page to get the products list . I also use it in a hidden popup box of this page which is product creation component .

When I call the pinia action **fetchProductsList(cat1)** in create-product component it fetch products of cat1. But it also change the result of products in products page.

I want to use different instance of product store on products page and product creation component to get different result of products. But I am getting the same result.

Is there any way to create different instance of same pinia store in same page so that i can get different result for productStore.products as per my needs ??

```
    import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
    
    export const useProductsStore = defineStore('products', {
    
        state: () =>
         ({ 
           
           products: [],
    
           
         }),
    
        getters: {
            getProducts: state => state.products
        },
    
        actions: {
    
            async fetchProductsList(category){
    
                return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    
                    axios.get(`/api/products?product_cat=${category}`)
                    .then((response) => { 
                        this.products = response.data 
                        resolve(response)
                    })
                    .catch((errors)=>{
                        reject(errors)
                    })
                })
                       
            },
    
          
        },

})
```

Comment: As far I know Pinia & Vuex are create to store common data and share it easily in multiple components. So I think there will be no easy way. You can just use another pinia store for this type purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using pinia properly. A store contains states that are shared among components, so it should have only one instance. In your case, I think you should create another store that is used for `CreateProduct` component. That store maybe contains state `newProducts` and a getter `allProducts` that are combined from `products` in `ProductStore` and `newProducts`.

Answer (score 0):

Posva ( creator of Pinia ) suggests this [here](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/771)

```
const options = {}
defineStore('one', {...options})
defineStore('two', {...options})
```